Reduce glass reflections
I want to make a glass with some object inside.
But the way it is now, the outside reflections are too strong, making it harder to see the object inside (as in the wall on the right side of the picture below)
Currently I have this:

I want to be able to reduce the reflections on the right side of the picture, so the ball inside is more visible.

Changing IOR is not a solution, changing IOR totally changes the apparent position of the object inside
Changing IOR level in "specular" section doesn't seem to do anything substantial
Mixing a transparent shader causes the ball to appear in two different positions (the principled position with IOR = 1.3 and the transparent position with IOR = 1)


Maybe try to use a Layer Weight node as factor between your setup and a Transparent node? Could you please share your file so that we can give a try?

Use a refraction bsdf?

@Leander, sounds like a good way. It solves my problem but generates another: black regions inside the glass.

@moonboots, the file has just a cube, a ball and the material shown in the picture (the material of the ball is irrelevant)

ok but it's always easier for use to use your current file rather than to redo the thing, have you tried a Layer Weight node?
